# Conversion of single explicit label to multiple binary labels in a .CSV file

Tags: excel, csv

I have a .csv file of the following form :

```
NameOfFile, Type
Example, Word Document;
         Picture;
         PDF;
Example2, Word Document;
Example3, Picture;
```

I would like to convert it to this form using a program:

```
Name of File, Word Document, Picture, PDF
Example, 1, 1, 1
Example2, 1, 0, 0
Example3, 0, 1, 0
```

So we're going from explicitly writing down the type, to having a binary feature which shows the type.

I assume there must be some clever way of doing this, since I'd imagine people fairly commonly need to do it.

What is my best practice method for doing this?

Comment: Is your first `NameOfFile` which is called `Example` truly not repeated down the rows? There's just a single instance of it, then blanks below?

Comment: @JNevill No, it is not repeated, there is a single instance. Each "Type" is separated by a semi-colon and a return :).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fill the blanks (select *entire* column, HOME > Editing - Find & Select, Go To Special..., check Blanks, `=`, Up, Ctrl+Enter) then create a PivotTable with `NameofFile` for ROWS, `Type` for COLUMNS and Count of Type for VALUES. Order to suit and under PivotTable Options...., check For empty cells show: and add `0`.

[image: SO27150945 example]

[image: Keyboard]

Comment: This is a great use-case for pivot tables.

Comment: @pnuts Can you please explain this a little further - for fill in the blanks, do I select the entire column, what is special, blanks, "=", Up and Ctrl + Enter)? Thanks :)